# How to skip the exit code after executing a command in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, aws-cli

I have a shell script that includes several commands.
For some of them, after it has been executed, I have to press P to quit the hint then the next command could proceed.
[image: Picture1]
[image: Picture2]

I want to know how to exit the hint automatically after the command gets executed, or input the keyword P automatically to exit it.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't post images with text. Please replace images with its text. See: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can basically pipe it to cat just like following:

```
$ ./deploy_eb_dev.sh | cat
```